# Create a React app, and disable the screen only visible in development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Is there a way to disable this screen? I don't want to run the production build yet.

Edit: Under the create-react-app you have the option to do either a development build or a production build. They run on either port :3000 or :5000 respectively. Under the production build this screen is disabled when an error occurs. When in the development build, this screen occurs when an error happens or when a crash is about to happen. The problem is that I want to run this under the development build BUT without this error screen to show up when an error happens. Why not just fix the error? Im going to, but because this will be client facing I don't want this screen to show up when an error happens.

[image]

Comment: Why not just fix the error?

Comment: The issue is that the production build runs on port 5000. And the front-end is communicating to a backend express server and for some reason it only works when the front end is running on port 3000. I wanted to suppress the warning while I find a fix.

Comment: I voted to reopen, but you may ignore that request. I found this question helpful because I was working on an Error boundary and Error view where the overlay isn't helpful while developing on the Error view. But there's another question that is more suitable in this context. Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589819/disable-error-overlay-in-development-mode

Comment: I have one answer for this just reload the window once

Answer (score 8):

As of right now, you can't disable the error overlay in create-react-app.

Until you fix the error, you can click the "X" on the top-right corner to close the overlay.

You can also open an issue on https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app to ask for a way to disable it.

Comment: Cool. I hadn't noticed the "X" on the top-right corner before. That's good enough for me.