# Possible to dismiss the browser compile error and show the react errorboundary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compiler-errors

I have an app where I want to implement reacts errorboundary:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ErrorView from './components/ErrorView'

class ErrorBoundary extends Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false,
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: any) {
    // Update state so the next render will show the fallback UI.
    return { hasError: true }
  }
  componentDidCatch(error: any, info: any) {
    // Display fallback UI
    this.setState({ hasError: true })
    console.log('error', error)
    console.log('info', info)
    console.log('I have error')
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    // logErrorToMyService(error, info);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      // You can render any custom fallback UI
      return <ErrorView />
    } else {
      return this.props.children
    }
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary
```

I put my app inside of the Errorboundary:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <App />
  </ErrorBoundary>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Inside one of the children in the app component i have created a component that is trying to map an empty array. I do this in order to get an error and hopefully get to my errorview.

What happens: 
I get an error and the errorView gets displayed but just a second after I get the red box error saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

This is in dev enviorment and frankly Im scared to put it in production before I can verify that only the erroview wil get shown,

is there a way to supress the rendering of the error in the browser?
I still get the error in the console I just dont want it in the browser render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ok, the error overlay is part of the development environment, you can close it and see your `ErrorView`.

After the production build, the overlay will be disabled and all errors will be directed to `ErrorView`.

For disabling the `error-overlay` [refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589819/disable-error-overlay-in-development-mode), you need to `eject` and disable `webpackHotDevClient` in the webpack config (which highly not recommended).

Or adding to your global CSS:

```
iframe {
    display: none;
}
```

---

If you wonder what Error Boundary actually does, [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57943149/react-error-boundaries-not-working-with-react/57943193#57943193).