# React Error Boundaries not working with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-error-boundary

This is my Error Boundary file -

```
class ErrorHandling extends Component {
    state = { hasError: false }

    componentDidCatch() {
        this.setState({ hasError: true })
    }

    render() {
        // debugger
        if (this.state.hasError) {
            return <div>Error in Component</div>
        }
        return this.props.children
    }
}
```

And the other file is -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Intentionally I have added syntax error below 'd'

function Intermediate(props) {
    return <h1>hi</h1>;d
}
export default Intermediate
```

And in my App.js

```
<ErrorHandling>
  <Intermediate />
</ErrorHandling>
```

It is causing the application to break without catching the error. Here is the error is seen on the browser screen

[image]

The more detailed version here-
https://codepen.io/meghana1991/pen/abojydj?editors=0010

When I use the same code in my local with multiple files as above listed, it doesn't work

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can't catch compile-time errors, the [**Error Boundaries**](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) are for run-time errors within the UI.

Refer to [Compile time vs run time errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time).

Moreover, you have to [use `getDerivedStateFromError`](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) in order to add additional render on fall back UI:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false,
    error: { message: '', stack: '' },
    info: { componentStack: '' }
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError = error => {
    return { hasError: true };
  };

  componentDidCatch = (error, info) => {
    this.setState({ error, info });
  };

  render() {
    const { hasError, error, info } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;

    return hasError ? <ErrorComponent/> : children;
  }
}
```

For checking your `ErrorBoundary`, throw an error from **a reachable** section in the component tree [**which is not**](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries):

- Event handlers
- Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame callbacks)
- Server side rendering
- Errors thrown in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

```
const ButtonComponent = () => {
  throw Error("error!");
  return <></>;
};
```

> Note: **In development env you will always see the error overlay unless you turn it off or close it with the X button.**

---

Full example:

```
const ErrorComponent = () => {
  return <h1>Something went wrong</h1>;
};

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false,
    error: { message: "", stack: "" },
    info: { componentStack: "" }
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError = error => {
    return { hasError: true };
  };

  componentDidCatch = (error, info) => {
    this.setState({ error, info });
  };

  render() {
    const { hasError, error, info } = this.state;
    console.log(error, info);
    const { children } = this.props;

    return hasError ? <ErrorComponent /> : children;
  }
}

const ButtonComponent = () => {
  throw Error("error!");
  return <></>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <ButtonComponent />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Error-Boundary Example]

Comment: Tried this now. But unfortunately not working. I still see the error on my app screen.

Comment: In development env you will always see the error overlay unless you turn it off or close it with the `X` button.

Comment: Also add to your question what you seeing, we can't guess

Comment: Added. Please check

Comment: I edited the answer, its compile-time error, your application not even starting you can't catch it dynamically

Comment: https://codepen.io/meghana1991/pen/abojydj?editors=0010 Here it is working as expected. The same code when used with different file for each component, it breaks

Comment: You got a runtime error, thats not the same, try recreating with files here https://codesandbox.io

Comment: this is not working for me, this button click error throwing method ?? any clues

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed I've added a full example with a sandbox

Comment: @DennisVash sandbox you provided shows default error view ? nothing from error boundary shows up on button click ?

Comment: @ShamseerAhammed Updated the example, you can't catch errors from event handlers like `onClick`, thank you for catching it up.

Comment: @DennisVash Correct, in such case you can use this npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary

Comment: thank you you saved a lot of time for me of searching for the issue that the error still appears in the development env.
Thank you.

Comment: Use native API like `.catch` in promises, depending on your async case.

Comment: @DennisVash Any idea how to disable error overlays in development? I want to check my fallback UI when there is an error

Comment: Seems like your example is also working with runtime.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is: the nice fallback UI you can see in the React docs example only appears **in production**. So you have to run the suggested by `create-react-app` (id you use it) command:

```sh
npm run build
# wait for it to finish
serve -s build
```

Then open `localhost:5000` in your browser (if you see this address in the terminal mentioned). This way the React docs example works fine.