# How to fix react error overlay, not being shown?

Tags: reactjs

So, whenever i get an error on my react app, the page either goes white or it freezes but content is still visible. I notice that when I was working on CSB i would be getting an error overlay whenever the app ran into errors. I've done a lot fo research as to how to implement the error overlay yet none helped me. I have visited this solution:
[Disable error overlay in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589819/disable-error-overlay-in-development-mode)
Using latest Node JS

Comment: same thing is happening to me.  it's like i run the react app and i can't interact with my UI...because upon inspection, there is an iframe over everything.....but i can't actually "see" it.

Comment: Any work around on this? I encountered this issue as well